# Virtual SPDT with half-bridge and op-amp comparator

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis

I have the following circuit composed of an op-amp comparator and a mosfet half-bridge:

[image]

I would like to "confirm" the following:

- if VBUS is floating, nothing will happen. Especially, there will be no current flowing from 4V2 (source) to SINK.
- if VBUS is a source at 5V, then there will be current flowing from VBUS to SINK which voltage will be a little bit less but close to 5.0V. There will be no current flowing between VBUS and 4V2.
- if VBUS is a sink, then there will be current flowing from 4V2 to VBUS which voltage will be a little bit less but close to 4.2V. There will be no current flowing between 4V2 and SINK.

If this is not correct, what is is wrong?

PS: Datasheets:
https://www.vishay.com/docs/70880/70880.pdf
https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/lmv331.pdf

Comment: The way the schematic is, you will have current from S1 to S2 if VS1>VS2 as you have two forward biased body diodes, no matter what you do to the gates and drain.  The rest of the schematic is a bit too vague (eg the LMV331 is an open collector output, which will be floating if IN->IN+, causing your gates to float as well).  Connecting the output directly to a low impedance voltage source will destroy the comparator.

Comment: probably won't destroy the comparitor unless VCC goes below ground. the PNP base is good for 5V of protection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this circuit will not do what you want.

1: the  comparator inputs are outside the working range

2: the comparitor cannot source current from its output, it can only sink current